# poll() and EOF: redirect file descriptors and do filtering

Tags: c, linux, solaris, aix

On Linux/SunOS/AIX, assuming that PARENT_READ_FD represents the standard output of a parent process and WRITE_FD represents the standard input of the current process, do you know of a different/better way to "redirect" the output of the parent process to the current process and apply filtering (ebcdic->utf8) until there is essentially nothing else to read?

Working code below:

```
void redirect() {
  char tmp[1];
  while (read(PARENT_READ_FD, tmp, 1)) {
    // filter/convert tmp here [code section omitted for clarity]
    write(WRITE_FD, tmp, 1);
    if (poll(&(struct pollfd) { .fd = PARENT_READ_FD, .events = POLLIN }, 1, 0) == 0) break;
  }
}
```

Thank you for looking

Comment: You could omit the poll part, instead check the return values of read and write (and errno). Also read block-wize (say 64KB) instead of byte-wise. (You can still transform the data, the read-size has nothing to do with it.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading just one byte at a time, read the entire pipe buffer size of data (check the particular operating system manuals to find out the number or the system call to do so). In Linux this number is now dynamic, depends on the file descriptor; you can find the size with `fcntl(fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ);` - if this errors out, you'd default to some conservative estimate such as 65536...

Comment: Not shown in the code above, but the contents will be modified on the fly. Otherwise, yes, would just pipe().

Comment: @JeromeIbanes in that case do add it to the question. Those are the *important details*, i.e. "I am doing a filter"

Comment: if using fcntl(fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ); should I make the read() non-blocking?